What are the new powers given to Superman in the animated TV series "My Adventures with Superman"?
In the animated TV series My Adventures with Superman, there is a reimagined version of Superman. He has some special abilities compared to the normal Superman we know.
What are these additional abilities? Some of them that I know are generating lightning from his body in S2E6 while fighting a robot disguised as a Thanagarian warrior, and containing a nuclear blast in S2E2. What are all the powers which he possesses?



I believe he was actually capable of generating lightning during his "Superman Blue" phase in the 90s comics, so that one isn't strictly "new".

I must admit, I never considered that a major issue with writing new, interesting stories about Superman was that he had too little power.

MAWS Superman features the standard suite of traditional powers in the mainstream contemporary era: super strength, flight, durability, heat vision, cold breath, super speed, and super senses.
The main unique emphasis of MAWS, up to now (following the conclusion of Season 2 with Season 3 in production), is technological and a very visible and apparent bio-electrical aura. Sun-Dipping makes a last minute appearance as well.
Tech
The technological "powers" are mostly tied to the logistics of his suit. He undergoes a "magic girl" transformation where the suit can appear from nowhere and replace his existing clothes, glasses, and hair without explanation. There is the suggestion of some latent psychic influence as his suit is as he wills it and not exactly mirrored by anything we see in MAWS's portrayal of Krypton. Then after learning about Krypton and meeting Kara and having an emotional breakthrough, his suit changes and Kara gains the same ability and a matching suit.
Aura
The bio-electrical aura is a more visual presentation of an underlying Superman "lubricant" to rationalize many of his traditional feats (ex: why doesn't he cause sonic booms everywhere he goes, how can he catch Lois after a fall without snapping her spine, how can he lift objects that lack the structural integrity to hold together, etc) and appears in MAWS on various occasions when demonstrating either a new power or when a "catch-all" is needed. For example, the first time he uses cold breath in MAWS the field appears about and around his mouth.
It appears during the fire in Silas Stone's apartment to cover them both and protect them from the heat, something Superman can't do with his arms and invulnerability alone; suggesting that Silas is somehow protected from the environment / Superman extending his invulnerability to Silas. Later it is used to contain the a fusion-like blast, where Superman generates a spherical field around the artificial sun (as illustrated in your question above). It is used to deflect (as opposed to simply absorbing or tanking) Live Wire's lightning. Etc.
It broadly relates to the ability to create a field or shield, but also acts as a multipurpose "magic" to sprinkle on a situation that isn't covered by Superman's traditional powerset.
Sun Dipping
The Season 2 finale strongly suggests that MAWS Kryptonians can "sun dip" meaning increase their power above their normal baseline based on intense exposure to our Sun. This has mixed adoption throughout Superman history but has become relatively popular and assumed for modern / contemporary versions of Superman.
Future
All of these powers have appeared previously in various Superman portrayals (New52 Superman's suit was nanotech, 90s Superman Blue heavily emphasized wide application of energy / electrical powers, etc) but this is MAWS adaptation of that history. Given the anime-influence and being enamored with powers and their application, I wouldn't be surprised if additional powers, applications, or subsets appear in future seasons of MAWS. For example, the Solar Flare ability or perhaps the ability to metabolize other forms of radiation for different effects.
We won't know all of MAWS Superman's abilities until the series concludes, but I doubt we've seen the last of them.

That's an apt username.
